# Application executable run issue

Tags: c#

I developed a windows application which is running fine with out any issue in my system.I just copied the executable file in to the some other system which is upgraded from windows xp to windows 7.But When I double click the executable file to run the application in second system,I am getting below error.

**CLR error: 80004005
The program will now terminate**

Both are having same system configuration.[Windows 7 operating system,.Net framework 4.5.2].I want to know why this issue is coming in second system and required steps to resolve it.

Comment: Right-Click the .exe file and run as admin; see if that runs the program.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to reinstall the .Net framework, I had the same problem.

Just uninstall it, and try to reinstall it.

If its not working, you may need to install .Net for each user on the machine (because security issues)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for giving reply.I already tried the first option.i.e. Uninstall and reinstall the framework.But my issue still not resolved.I am not understood your second answer.i.e. install ..Net for each user?you mean am i need to install the same .net framework for all the existing users of that system.

Comment: sometimes your user don't have permissions to access those files, try to install .Net for YOUR user specific.